# Getting "StandardOutputEncoding is only supported when standard output is redirected" in GitHub Actions

Tags: powershell, github-actions, powershell-core

I'm running [`gitversion.exe`](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion) as part of a GitHub actions workflow on Windows using `pwsh`:

```
$versionInfo = (& .\gitversion.exe) | ConvertFrom-Json
```

While working beautifully on my local machine, it fails on the actions runner:

```
ResourceUnavailable: D:\a\azure-pipelines-pre-and-post-tasks\azure-pipelines-pre-and-post-tasks\build.ps1:178
Line |
 178 |  $versionInfo = (& .\gitversion.exe) | ConvertFrom-Json
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Program 'gitversion.exe' failed to run: StandardOutputEncoding is only supported when standard output
     | is redirected.At
     | D:\a\azure-pipelines-pre-and-post-tasks\azure-pipelines-pre-and-post-tasks\build.ps1:178 char:17 +
     | $versionInfo = (& .\gitversion.exe) | ConvertFrom-Json +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
```

I'm running other executables and capturing their output without issues in the same script, so there must be something special about `gitversion` than I don't fully grasp.

Repo with the current reproducible behavior is here:

- https://github.com/jessehouwing/azure-pipelines-pre-and-post-tasks/tree/78f8251d2c5e2fb64ce8a4497074ba4689568897

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, that was unexpected. First I stumbled upon a hint to change the input and output encoding of the PowerShell console:

```
[console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
```

And that revealed a new problem, namely that `gitversion.exe` wasn't a valid windows executable. It turned out to be the LFS pointer file.

```
ResourceUnavailable: D:\a\azure-pipelines-pre-and-post-tasks\azure-pipelines-pre-and-post-tasks\build.ps1:179
Line |
 179 |  $versionInfo = & .\gitversion.exe | ConvertFrom-Json
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Program 'gitversion.exe' failed to run: An error occurred trying to start process
     | 'D:\a\azure-pipelines-pre-and-post-tasks\azure-pipelines-pre-and-post-tasks\gitversion.exe' with
     | working directory 'D:\a\azure-pipelines-pre-and-post-tasks\azure-pipelines-pre-and-post-tasks'. The
     | specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
```

I had forgotten to add:

```
with:
  lfs: true
```

To my checkout task:

```
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    lfs: true
```

Whatever error was thrown by the operating system caused the error in the title of this post. But the real issue was the actual executable was missing.