# Powershell 7.2: ConvertFrom-Json - Date Handling

Tags: json, powershell, datetime, powershell-7.2

With Powershell 7.2 there seems to be a change in how a JSON is deserialized into an object in terms of dates -> instead of string it is now datetime. But I want to have the "old" behavior, i.e. that it is handled as string and NOT datetime.

How can I achieve that when using ConvertFrom-Json in Powershell 7.2 all dates are deserialized as string and not datetime?

**EDIT:**

```
$val = '{ "date":"2022-09-30T07:04:23.571+00:00" }' | ConvertFrom-Json
$val.date.GetType().FullName
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can't control how dates are parsed, currently. [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13598) proposes a new parameter to change that, but it is still in "open" state. As a workaround you might preprocess the JSON to make dates unrecognizable by `ConvertFrom-Json`, e. g. by inserting a non-whitespace prefix character. E. g. `'{ "date":"2022-09-30T07:04:23.571+00:00" }' -replace '"(\d+-\d+.\d+T\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+\+\d+:\d+)"', '"#$1"' | ConvertFrom-Json`

Comment: @zett42 Thanks for your response and suggestion. That is unfortunate... I would expect that if this kind of change is implemented that there is also an option to adjust the behavior, but obviously it is not. I hope this changes soon. Meanwhile I will try your approach :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a known issue, see: [`#13598` Add a -DateKind parameter to ConvertFrom-Json to control how System.DateTime / System.DateTimeOffset values are constructed](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13598). Yet I think there is no easy solution for this. One thing you might do is just invoke (Windows) PowerShell. <strike>Which isn't currently straights forward as well therefore I have created a small wrapper to send and receive complex objects between PowerShell sessions (see also my [`#18460 Invoke-PowerShell`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18460) purpose):</strike>

```
function Invoke-PowerShell ($Command) {
    $SerializeOutput = @"
         `$Output = $Command
         [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize(`$Output)
"@
    $Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($SerializeOutput)
    $EncodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($Bytes)
    $PSSerial = PowerShell -EncodedCommand $EncodedCommand
    [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize($PSSerial)
}
```

Usage:

```
Invoke-PowerShell { '{ "date":"2022-09-30T07:04:23.571+00:00" }' | ConvertFrom-Json }

date
----
2022-09-30T07:04:23.571+00:00
```

---

#### Update

As commented by **[mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)**, I clearly complicated the answer.

> Calling via powershell.exe is a pragmatic workaround (albeit slow and Windows-only), but note that you don't need a helper function: if you pass a *script block* to powershell.exe (or pwsh.exe) *from PowerShell*, Based64 CLIXML-based serialization happens automatically behind the scenes: try `powershell.exe -noprofile { $args | ConvertFrom-Json } -args '{ "date":"2022-09-30T07:04:23.571+00:00" }'` For that reason, I don't think there's a need for an Invoke-PowerShell cmdlet.

```
$Json = '{ "date":"2022-09-30T07:04:23.571+00:00" }'
powershell.exe -noprofile { $args | ConvertFrom-Json } -args $Json

date
----
2022-09-30T07:04:23.571+00:00
```

Comment: Given that I have a script that executes many jobs in parallel and each job processes a JSON file, how can I achieve that with this approach? So far I am running into errors:

"Program 'powershell.exe' failed to run: StandardOutputEncoding is only supported when standard output is redirected."

For 

"[pscustomobject]$jsonObject = powershell.exe -noprofile { $args | ConvertFrom-Json } -args $json"

Comment: Reading this [Getting "StandardOutputEncoding is only supported when standard output is redirected" in GitHub Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70250915/1701026), I guess there is something specific with the json file. Possibly empty? Special characters? What happens when you open a (Windows) PowerShell session and just do `$YourJson | ConvertFrom-Json`. Maybe it is a good idea to open a new question with a [mcve] and a specific Json example.

Answer (score 2):

- **[iRon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74316212/45375)** provides a **pragmatic solution via the *Windows PowerShell* CLI, `powershell.exe`**, relying on the fact that `ConvertFrom-Json` there does *not* automatically transform ISO 8601-like timestamp strings to `[datetime]` instances.

  - Hopefully, the proposal in the GitHub issue he links to, [#13598](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13598), will be implemented in the future, which would then simplify the solution to:

    ```bash
     # NOT YET IMPLEMENTED as of PowerShell 7.2.x
     '{ "date":"2022-09-30T07:04:23.571+00:00" }' |
       ConvertFrom-Json -DateTimeKind None
    ```
- However, a `powershell.exe` workaround has two disadvantages: (a) it is *slow* (a separate PowerShell instance in a child process must be launched), and (b) it is Windows-only. The solution below is a generalization of your own approach that avoids these problems.

---

Here's a **generalization** of [your own in-process approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74318647/45375):

- It injects a NUL character (`` "`0" ``) at the start of each string that matches the pattern of a timestamp - the assumption is that the input itself never contains such characters, which is fair to assume.
- This, as in your approach, prevents [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) from recognizing timestamp strings as such, and leaves them untouched.
- The `[pscustomobject]` graph that `ConvertFrom-Json` outputs must then be *post-processed* in order to remove the injected NUL characters again.

  - This is achieved with a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call that contains a helper script block that *recursively* walks the object graph, which has the advantage that it  **works with JSON input whose timestamp strings may be *at any level of the hierarchy*** (i.e. they may also be in properties of *nested* objects).
  - **Note**: The assumption is that the timestamp strings are only ever contained as *property values* in the input; more work would be needed if you wanted to handle input JSON such as `'[ "2022-09-30T07:04:23.571+00:00" ]'` too, where the strings are input objects themselves.

```bash
# Sample JSON.
$val = '{ "date":"2022-09-30T07:04:23.571+00:00" }'

$val -replace '"(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}[+-]\d{2}:\d{2}")', "`"`0" |          #"
  ConvertFrom-Json |
  ForEach-Object {
    # Helper script block that walks the object graph
    $sb = {
      foreach ($o in $args[0]) { 
        if ($o -is [Array]) { # nested array -> recurse
          foreach ($el in $o) { & $sb $el } # recurse
        }
        elseif ($o -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]) {
          foreach ($prop in $o.psobject.Properties) { 
            if ($prop.Value -is [Array]) {
              foreach ($o in $prop.Value) { & $sb $o } # nested array -> recurse
            }
            elseif ($prop.Value -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]) { 
              & $sb $prop.Value # nested custom object -> recurse
            }
            elseif ($prop.Value -is [string] -and $prop.Value -match '^\0') { 
              $prop.Value = $prop.Value.Substring(1) # Remove the NUL again.
            }
          } 
        }
      }
    }
    # Call the helper script block with the input object.
    & $sb $_
    # Output the modified object.
    if ($_ -is [array]) {
      # Input object was array as a whole (implies use of -NoEnumerate), output as such.
      , $_ 
    } else {
      $_
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the input from @zett42 here my solution:

Assuming we know the regex pattern of the date used in the JSON I get the JSON as string, add a prefix so that `ConvertFrom-Json` does not convert dates to datetime but keeps it as string, convert it with `ConvertFrom-Json` to a `PSCustomObject`, do whatever I need to do on the object, serialize it back to a JSON string with `ConvertTo-Json` and then remove the prefix again.

```
[string]$json = '{ "date":"2022-09-30T07:04:23.571+00:00", "key1": "value1" }'

[string]$jsonWithDatePrefix = $json -replace '"(\d+-\d+.\d+T\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+\+\d+:\d+)"', '"#$1"'

[pscustomobject]$jsonWithDatePrefixAsObject = $jsonWithDatePrefix | ConvertFrom-Json

$jsonWithDatePrefixAsObject.key1 = "value2"

[string]$updatedJsonString = $jsonWithDatePrefixAsObject | ConvertTo-Json

[string]$updatedJsonStringWithoutPrefix = $updatedJsonString -replace '"(#)(\d+-\d+.\d+T\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+\+\d+:\d+)"', '"$2"'

Write-Host $updatedJsonStringWithoutPrefix
```

Answer (score 0):

Two additional ways to change the date format:

#### `Get-Node`

Using this [`Get-Node`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74337640/1701026) which is quiet similar to **[mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)** recursive function:

```
$Data = ConvertFrom-Json $Json
$Data |Get-Node -Where { $_.Value -is [DateTime] } | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Value  = GetDate($_.Value) -Format 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffzzz' -AsUTC
}
$Data
```

#### DIY

Or do-it-yourself and build your own Json deserializer:

```
function ConvertFrom-Json {
    [CmdletBinding()][OutputType([Object[]])] param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeLine = $True, Mandatory = $True)][String]$InputObject,
        [String]$DateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz', # Default: ISO 8601, https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/datesinjson.htm
        [Switch]$AsLocalTime,
        [Switch]$AsOrdered
    )
    function GetObject($JObject) {
        switch ($JObject.GetType().Name) {
            'JValue' {
                switch ($JObject.Type) {
                    'Boolean'  { $JObject.Value }
                    'Integer'  { 0 + $JObject.Value }                                                 # https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14264
                    'Date'     { Get-Date $JObject.Value -Format $DateFormat -AsUTC:(!$AsLocalTime) } # https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13598
                    Default    { "$($JObject.Value)" }
                }
            }
            'JArray' {
                ,@( $JObject.ForEach{ GetObject $_ } )
            }
            'JObject' {
                $Properties = [Ordered]@{}
                $JObject.ForEach{ $Properties[$_.Name] = GetObject $_.Value }
                if ($AsOrdered) { $Properties } else { [PSCustomObject]$Properties }                  # https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/17405
            }
        }
    }
    GetObject ([Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject]::Parse($InputObject))
}
```

**Usage:**

```
ConvertFrom-Json $Json -DateFormat 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffzzz' |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9
```